# How to change the interior colorindex of a conditionally formatted cell

Tags: vba, excel, format

If a cell is conditionally formatted I can't simply change the interior color index by `cells(row , col).interior.colorindex = 6`

I tried this but the format of the cell is lost

```
                    val = wRes.Cells(i, p)
                    wRes.Cells(i, p).Clear
                    wRes.Cells(i, p).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    wRes.Cells(i, p) = val
```

like certain cells have dates and other have numbers in "00,000" this format
are lost.

Comment: Conditional formatting overrides all other formatting so .... for all intents and purposes, you cannot get there from here.

Comment: If I clear that cell no conditional formatting will be applied for that

Comment: Try `wRes.Cells(i, p).FormatConditions.Delete`

Comment: Thanks problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use,

```
wRes.Cells(i, p).FormatConditions.Delete
```

... to reshape the Applies to: range of existing [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) to exclude the cell you want to change.